# get many to many values and which of them are selected in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-and-belongs-to-many

```
Contacts:
id
name

Tags:
id
name

ContactTags:
contact_id
tag_id
```

In Contacts model:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tags::class, "contacts_tags", "contact_id", "tag_id");
}
```

So if I do

```
$contact = Contacts::findOrFail($id);
dd($contact->tags);
```

I successfully get the `tags` associated with the `contact`. But how can I get all `tags` and a flag indicating which one of those is associated?

I'm trying to prevent fetching all `tags`, loop them and with each iteration loop all `contact_tags` and check if `tag_id` matches. I want to display a list of checkboxes with all tags and check the ones that are in the relation.

Comment: Are you build the edit page for contacts?

Comment: yes, I'm building the create and edit page for contacts where the available tags are shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code can help you, but I'm using the SELECT multiple component. You can easily adapt it to use the CHECKBOX component.

Contacts model:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tags::class, "contacts_tags", "contact_id", "tag_id");
}
```

ContactController.php

```
public function edit(Contact $contact)
{
    $tags = Tag::all();
    return view('contacts.edit',compact('contact', 'tags'));        
}
```

edit.blade.php

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Tags:</strong>
                <select name="tags_id[]" multiple>
                    @foreach ($tags as $tag)
                        @if( $contact->tags->contains($tag) )
                            <option value="{{ $tag->id }}" selected>{{ $tag->name }}</option>
                        @else
                            <option value="{{ $tag->id }}">{{ $tag->name }}</option>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Update in ContactController.php

```
public function update(Request $request, Post $contact)
{   
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'tags_id' => ['array'],
        ]);

    $contact->update($request->all());
    $contact->tags()->sync($validatedData['tags_id']); 

    return redirect()->route('contact.index')->with('success', 'Contact successfully updated!');
}
```

The validation is just an example. The $validatedData has no use here, but it can be used to update the contact if you validate the other fields.